# May I use SQL Server in a Google Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Does google computte engine offer SQL Server 2012 licensing? Web Edition to be more specific.

I have not found any documentation on this matter here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/infrastructure-software?hl=es

Comment: Looks like it's BYOL: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows#sql_server_license_requirements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not *currently* offer it, however you can [get a windows server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/?hl=es) and install SQL on it yourself. [They have guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows?hl=es#sql_server_license_requirements) when it comes to how to license it.

> Microsoft License Mobility for Google Cloud Platform enables you to
>   deploy eligible Microsoft Windows Server Applications on Google Cloud
>   Platform with existing application licenses. This allows you to easily
>   move your workloads to Google Cloud Platform, without any additional
>   Microsoft software licensing fees.

**Update 10/12/2016.**

As mentioned in a comment by [darius](https://serverfault.com/users/163618/darius) they now have it [on offer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/#sql_server).

Comment: It appears that they now to have images with SQL pre-installed :https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/#sql_server

Comment: @Darius Thx, added!